# VeraCrypt taking a very long time (~1 hour) to create volume?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, veracrypt

To get to 50% on a 1.8TB volume, VeraCrypt has taken about 30 minutes. If it takes another 30 minutes to finish, that's 1h to create the volume. Is this normal? (if it in't should start over after figuring out what went wrong). The process has also rendered my laptop almost unusably slow during this process. In Activity Monitor VeraCrypt jumps between 30% and 200% CPU, and the laptop is *very* sluggish. Here are some system stats (very little else running other than a couple of chrome tabs and VeraCrypt):

[image]

Notes:

- Using AES128
- exFAT file system option

Comment: I don't see this really as a security question, even though a security program is involved. Also, there are [many easy to find information](https://www.google.com/search?q=veracrypt+time+to+create+volume) on the internet which suggest that what you see is not uncommon. Also, the process is primarily I/O bound, i.e. depends on the speed of your disk. With 500 MB/s (typical value for SSD) it simply will take around an hour to write 1.8 GByte.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you mean 1 hour for 1.8TB or 1.8GB?

Comment: Right, I've meant 1.8TB.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich when pressing a button in any UI (web or otherwise), it's standard to expect a response within a few thousand milliseconds. If some security related feature takes a *lot* longer - and that is specifically related to security - then it's by definition security related

Comment: You got your response - it started to create the volume, didn't it? Doing work uses the cpu, and for all that we know, it could be 100MHz Netbook from the nineties :-)

Comment: @stevec: *"If some security related feature takes a lot longer - and that is specifically related to security - then it's by definition security related"* - bold statement and I don't agree with it. With such a broad interpretation nearly everything would be somehow related to security and nearly everything like somehow is actually related to it. But I would see the scope of this site much more narrow than issues of response time to UI actions.

Comment: what ever you do Do Not Stop the process until it is done.

Comment: @Moab I actually stopped it because it was taking too long and I needed the use of my computer back. I was creating a new volume on an otherwise completely empty external hard disk. I think it shouldn't matter in that case because I wasn't directly encrypting files, but rather creating a new volume?

Answer (score 1):

#### Encryption is not instant (it can take a long time)

A [how to geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/305540/how-to-encrypt-your-macs-time-machine-backup/) says:

> This one-time process is not fast ... a one terabyte drive can easily take more than 24 hours

And [on TrueCrypt](https://paulrrogers.com/2015/10/veracrypt-too-slow-and-complex/) (VeraCrypt's predecessor):

> I created similar 2TB volume with Truecrypt and it completed successfully in less than 24 hours.

This may not be at all obvious to those who haven't encrypted more than 1 GB data before, since the long wait may be a new phenomena that's obvious to those who do it regularly, but not to newbies.

So the quick answer is: encryption takes time - sometimes a day or more for 1-2TB depending on I/O. So VeraCrypt taking several hours for a single TB is somewhat expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal.

Let's take some **ball park numbers**:

A typical SATA interface to a spinning rust drive would support write speeds at around 12 GB/minute.

Initializing the drive requires writing to the entire drive.

Assuming 1 TB for convenience, and using decimal vice hex multipliers.

1 TB = 1000 GB

1000 GB / (12 GB/minute) = 83 minutes = 1.7 Hours

So 2 TB would be twice this, or 3 Hours.

A drive in use would require first reading then writing, slowing the encryption process further.

A slower laptop drive would take longer, and a solid state drive would be much faster.